# Use returned object from laravel controller in vue template

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-blade

please how can i use object returned from laravel controller in vue component like we use in blade

for example i have 2 table user and role user has one role

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string

roles
    id - integer
    name - string
```

in controller i return an object of type user and i use it like this in blade

```
{{$user->role['name']}}
```

like this i can get the name of role

how can i get the role name of the returns user in Vue template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to pass `$user` directly to component. In this case make sure to append `role` data in `user` model.

```
<example-component :user="{{ $user->toArray() }}"></example-component>
```

And then inside vue component you can print `{{ user.role.name }}`

You can also add an attribute in `User.php` model and append it

```
protected $appends = ['role_name'];

public function getRoleNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->role->name;
}
```

And then inside `ExampleComponent` you can print `{{ user.role_name }}`